# Leaflet Geodata Marker clustering and intersection

Tags: qgis, geoserver, leaflet, clustering

I'm having a problem with grouping(clustering) markers

I have a list GeoJSON features that I display as markers in the leaflet. And it looks like this:

[image: MapMarkers]

These points are saved in my Database and are located on my Geoserver.

And when fetch them from DB I get it like this, then I loop over them and add them as markers.

```
const points = [
  { lat: 48.371768, lng: 16.723857 },
  { lat: 48.354206, lng: 16.703258 },
  { lat: 48.401474, lng: 16.727156 },
  { lat: 48.283497, lng: 16.545787 },
  { lat: 48.361275, lng: 16.699054 },
  { lat: 48.283497, lng: 16.545787 },
];
```

The problem that I'm having is that I have to summarize points within a specific radius and group (cluster) them automatically.

I have to expand points for some specific radius say 100 meters

Like in Turf js buffer option:

https://turfjs.org/

Like here:

[image]

And in Points where those circles intersect with each other, add an additional marker with those I already have

I have tried with Leaflet Clustering marker

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster

But haven't had any luck, markers are not displayed at all.

Here is my code so far:

```
var markers = L.markerClusterGroup({
  maxClusterRadius: function (zoom) {
    return 10;
  },
});

points.forEach((point) => {
  const location = { latlng: { lat: point, point: event.lng } };
  var marker = L.marker(location.latlng);
  markers.addLayer(marker);
  this.layers.markersLayer.instance.addLayer(markers);
});
```

And that works fine, but I would like to cluster points by distance in meters instead of pixels like in `maxClusterRadius`.

Comment: You should (1) Look for errors in your [browser's console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console) (2) Re-read the Leaflet.Markercluster documentation and (3) Realize that the `maxClusterRadius` option should be a `Number` but your're passing a `Function` and expecting it to magically work.

Comment: @IvanSanchez It is also working with function, is there any way I could convert meters to pexel in this case for maxClusterRadius option

Comment: Yeah, that'd be the inverse of `map.distance()` - get the map width from `map.getSize()`, calculate the length (in meters) of a horizontal line crossing the map center [just as `L.Control.Scale` does](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/bc918d4bdc2ba189807bc207c77080fb41ecc196/src/control/Control.Scale.js#L71-L73), and do a bit of math to get the meter-to-pixel ratio for the current zoom level and latitude.

Comment: @IvanSanchez could you this post as a full answer so I can accept it +1

Answer (score 0):

Incase it helps anyone:

```
function getPixelsForDistance(map, distanceInMeters) {
    const centerPoint = map.latLngToContainerPoint(map.getCenter());
    const targetLatLng = map.containerPointToLatLng([centerPoint.x + distanceInMeters, centerPoint.y]);
    const targetPoint = map.latLngToContainerPoint(targetLatLng);
    return Math.abs(targetPoint.x - centerPoint.x);
}
```

and then call with

```
const clusterGroup = L.markerClusterGroup({
   maxClusterRadius: getPixelsForDistance(map, 50),
});
```